# The font-size could not be decreased using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm using bootstrap and I'm trying to make a hint paragraph's `p.tiny` text very tiny in size. Using developer's tools show me that the font could not be smaller if it is less than 15 px. The following is what I have tried:

```js
window.history.back();
```

```css
nav,
.container {
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  color: red;
}

div.panel * {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: AraJozoor-Regular, Arial, Ubuntu, serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 0px 2px #800000;
}

div.panel hr {
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

div.panel img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p.tiny {
  font-size: 8px !important;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <img src="/imgs/wrong.png" />
  <h1>Error: 1</h1>
  <h3>This Application Works Only With Javascript Enabled Browsers.</h3>
  <h3>Please contact the system Administrator.</h3>
  <div>Your browser: Chrome, Version: 61.0<sup>(*)</sup></div>

  <hr />
</div>
<p class="tiny">(*): It`s estimated information and it may not be accurate enough.</p>
```

I also tried to set the font size of `p.tiny` with proportional units, i.e `%` and `em` but that would not decrease the font size either.

Comment: is `.tiny` used as a other class declaration, do you have more of it?

Comment: I have just copied your code and it looks fine to me: https://codepen.io/andrasadam93/pen/NadGBE

Comment: The code you posted is fine. It must be something in you external stylesheet. What styles did the element inspector show you that were being applied?

Comment: @AndrewAdam this is probably just a test I would guess, as OP uses bootstrap, and we don't know whats in the css linked in as well.

Comment: @AndrewAdam You have made it bigger. However, my problem in decreasing it. i.e making it smaller.

Comment: uhm... then: https://codepen.io/andrasadam93/pen/NadGBE ? :D

Comment: @Dejan.S I beleive that there is no other `.tiny` class or `p.tiny` class defined in any other place. However, I tried, as your suggestion, to rename it to `p.tinyyy` and the same result occures too. I could not decrease the font less than 15px

Comment: Have you checked the CSS rules that are applied in the element inspector, as I suggested? You will see *exactly* what is being applied there.

Comment: Also disable all your external plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some browsers have a "minimum font-size" setting (for example Firefox: 10px) and they won't display text smaller than that to keep it always readable. This is purely a browser setting and overrides any CSS rules. I f you change this setting to 8px, you'll see the desired result, but other users won't, unless they change that setting in their browser.

Comment: I'm using Chrome ver 61. So there is no any mean that makes the browser obey the size we want?

Comment: In Chrome there's also a minimum font size setting. You can adjust it for yourself, but you can't force it on other users via your website code.

Comment: @SaidbakR I'm using Chrome v.60 and I can still see the p.tiny as 2px in Andrew Adams codepen (codepen.io/andrasadam93/pen/NadGBE), and I've never changed my min font size from the default, so unless you have you own min font size set to 15px, I'm not sure that's the problem?

Comment: @FluffyKitten Yes it seems that I have changed the default min font size of Chrome settings.

Comment: I use both chrome and firefox and I have never had a minimum font size affect my code on either browser - if there was the `font-size:0px` hack that so many people use on inline block elements would never work as it would come out at the minimum font size

Comment: @Pete I just tried in Firefox: 0px actually works as expected (i.e. nothing is displayed), but everything between 1px and 9px is shown as 10px text (which is the current minimum setting, which I think is the default, since I never changed it)

Comment: @Johannes I've never changed my settings (and have no plugins installed) and my font sizes are as I want them to be.  Most likely you will have some sort of plugin installed that is setting your minimum font size - this is a fiddle I made https://jsfiddle.net/bchx3qyg/ and my results: https://postimg.org/image/5xsbbj9fp/f67742d1/

Comment: @Pete No, I don't have any plugin like that. It's simply that setting. I was only just describing what I had just tried, that 0px worked, while 1-9 wouldn't work.

Comment: Hmmm, I just tested with a fresh install of firefox and then browsed to the minimum font size setting and it was set to none so not sure why yours would be set to 10px

Answer (score 0):

the code you provided in the question has the style and script tag between the `</head>` and `<body>` This is not legal. Try moving the tags?

here is a working version
plnkr.co/edit/FFB1K3j1dmUaWdBir5M9?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by 'not legal' ? While creating UI it is quite common to just throw a style next to the segment you are working on and then later refactor it.

Comment: @AndrewAdam You are only allowed to have a head and body tag inside of an HTML tag https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html

Comment: @JamesHarrington These are standards but not affects the render results.

Comment: Stack overflow stripped out the `</head> and <body>` from my question it makes more sense now

Comment: In reality, all modern browsers move the style and script tags into the head automagically. But that is beside the point. because it still works.

Comment: @AndrewAdam Putting anything outside of the HTML documents `<head>` & `<body>` tags is a really bad idea. Just because you can do it, does not mean that you should. The same goes for other people doing it — just because some guy, or gal, stuck a fork in their eye doesn't mean other people should.